# Embeddings (word or other) standard file format

Tags: word-embedding

I am creating my own word embeddings and I have various versions of them.

What is the standard way (if there is one) to save embeddings to files, so that others could easily read and use them later?

If there are several accepted methods, I'd appreciate an answer that explains each method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found how standard text format of word embeddings look like

```
<vocabulary_length> <embedding_dimensions>
<word1> <emb1_dim1> <emb1_dim2> ...... <emb1_dim_n>
<word2> <emb2_dim1> <emb2_dim2> ...... <emb2_dim_n>
.
.
<word_m> <embm_dim1> <embm_dim2> ...... <embm_dim_n>
```

Where in this example `vocabulary_length` is `m` and `embedding_dimensions` is `n`